# Sudo as another user and run command

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I am doing an online course and the current exercise sees me learning more about sudo. I had to log in as another user and run a command to acccess a password.
In my sudo exercise I have finally got myself logged in as the `pseudo` user with the discovered password from the first part of the question. Now I have to access a token in the file `/root/token.txt`. Whilst logged in as the user `pseudo` I can see from sudo -l the following:

```
user pseudo may run the following commands on sudo
            (ALL) NOPASSWD:  ALL
```

if I cd to the / directory and run ls -la I get

```
drwx------   2  root root 4096 Jun 18 1521 root
```

From the above I deduce only the owner has `rwx` permissions and that the owner is root. What I am struggling with is how do I access the token file when it would appear to me that I need root access, HELP please?

Comment: Do you know how to use `sudo` to execute commands that normally can be used by `root` only?

Comment: Hi Jos, yes I am familiar with sudo to execute commands normally only permissible by root. What i was confused by was how the command should be to open the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since user `pseudo` may run `ALL` commands, you should be able to access the file regardless of the directory's owner given that you are already logged in as `pseudo` e.g.

```
sudo cat /root/token.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider sudo as a bash command with options: -u for user, -g for group, where the "default" group is 0, and uid=root.
You can now make a special group, "root" - as here. I prefer to call it "admin" or "Administrators" and both "uid" and "gid" must match.